# How to detect value change that is made dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a modification to a project that is using JavaScript to dynamically populate text-box values with calculations made on changes of other text-boxes but I don’t want to alter the original JavaScript files.

How do I detect when a text-box value has been changed by the original JavaScript, I need to detect when values are changed then fire off my own functions.

I am open to using jquery if this is easier.

Tried:

```
   $("#total_amt").on("change", function() {
        alert("Handler for .change() called.");
    });
```

but this only works when I manually alter the value of total_amt not when it is changed dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The best solution is to raise your own event when you change the value and hook to that yourself. Something like this:

```
// after changing the value in code:
$('#total_amt').val(newValue).trigger('dynamicChange');

// event hook
$("#total_amt").on("change dynamicChange", function() {
    alert("Handler for .change() called.");
});
```

Comment: True, although personally I don't like triggering native events - I always trigger my own to keep a closer track on exactly whats happening and when.

Comment: I'm agree here but i prefer to use triggerHandler even change event doesn't bubble anyway

Comment: So there is no way to do this without altering the original code hmm

Comment: @user794846 without using an interval to check value or some kind of property change observers (which is bad), no!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $("#total_amt").on("input", function() {
     alert("Handler for .change() called.");
 });
```

*this is HTML5 thing* though won't work with the modern browsers,  for other browsers

```
var lastValue = '';
$("#total_amt").on('change keyup paste', function() {
    if ($(this).val() != lastValue) {
        lastValue = $(this).val();
        calert("Handler for .change() called.");
    }
});
```

Comment: <<this is HTML5 thing though won't work with the modern browsers, for other browsers>> you mean will work on modern browsers :)   Supported since IE9

Comment: Well, i am not sure if it supports thats why :)

Comment: BTW, oninput won't be fired for programmatically changed value

Comment: ugghhhh.... so trigger will be the only option for this? or might be another solution for this?

Comment: Trigger in sense `Rory McCrossan` suggested! below answer